# How separate the view and controller correctly?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have a problem. I would like to custom a button in my main view, so, in the controller of this view in viewDidLoad,  have this code :

```
   [self.buttonGenerate setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonGenerate setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButtonHighlight.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

But, im not sure is good relative to MVC pattern, this code is in my controller whereas it should be in view code.
Your opinion ? What is the good practise ?

(Sorry for my english)

thx you

Answer (score -1):

Ideally it would be in your view code.

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) on the MVC design pattern in Apple's docs.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find an article on [how to separate view logic from view controller](http://jpellat.com/how-to-separate-view-controllers-from-his-view-logic/). I hope it helps :)